# Why do I need to 'block copy' when I want to use the block?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

```
 ProductCenterController __weak *tempSelf = self;

 void(^block)(void) = ^{
    tempSelf.actIndView = ....
    [tempSelf.view addSubview:tempSelf.actIndView];
};

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(actionForThreadBlock:) toTarget:self withObject:block];
```

I find Leak - '_Block_copy_internal'...(I use ARC)
and then when I change the last line code to something like this ,the leak missing...:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(actionForThreadBlock:) toTarget:self withObject:[block copy]];
```

if I dont use [block copy], why it will cause a leak????

I think ,the block will release after the function and the thread will release all after finished...

how it will cause a leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks are created on the stack, so they are released when your method (scope) ends. Some time after your thread will try to execute the already deallocated block, ending in exception.

`Copy` moves the block from stack to heap memory, so it will live even after the original method ends.

Please refer to Apple documentation when the subject is discussed extensively.

Comment: ok... i see.. thx, but i dont know that why the leaks will show "_Block_copy_internal" note/

Comment: @GanLiting `detachNewThreadSelector...` retains and uses a block on the stack and that already corrupts memory. In this state, almost anything can happen. Using `copy` you will solve the cause of the error, trying to find how corrupted memory causes a leak has no purpose.